# incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby

I have just recently upgraded to ruby 1.92 and one of my monkey patches is failing with some sort of encoding error.  I have the following function:

```
  def strip_noise()
    return if (!self) || (self.size == 0)

    self.delete(160.chr+194.chr).gsub(/[,]/, "").strip
  end
```

That now gives me the following error:

> incompatible character encodings:
>   UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT

Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: Welcome to Ruby 1.9's Brave New World of character encodings! You might want to [read up on the topic](http://blog.grayproductions.net/categories/character_encodings).

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me at the moment anyway:

```
class String
  def strip_noise()
    return if empty? 
    self.mb_chars.normalize(:kd).gsub(/[^\x00-\x7F]/n,'')
  end
end
```

I need to do more testing but I can progress..

Answer (score 1):

```
class String
  def strip_noise
    return if empty? 
    ActiveSupport::Inflector.transliterate self, ''
  end
end

"#{160.chr}#{197.chr} string with noises" # => "\xA0\xC5 string with noises"
"#{160.chr}#{197.chr} string with noises".strip_noise # => "A string with noises"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you want:

```
  def strip_noise
    return if empty?
    sub = 160.chr.force_encoding(encoding) + 194.chr.force_encoding(encoding)
    delete(sub).gsub(/[,]/, "").strip
  end
```

Read more on the topic here: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/17/encodings-unabridged/

Comment: I now get "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8".  Are 160.chr and 194.chr not valid UTF-8 characters?

Comment: Dunno, apparently not. Why not place the actual characters in there instead of the bytes. Or cast the string itself to ASCII-8BIT?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do here, but `160.chr+194.chr` is not valid UTF-8: 160 is a continuation byte, and 194 is the first byte of a 2-byte character. Reversed they form the unicode character for "non breaking space".

If you want to remove all non-ASCII-7 characters, try this:

```
s.delete!("^\u{0000}-\u{007F}")
```